# Configuring Liferay to use HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, tomcat6, liferay-6

We have developed a `Application Portal` using `Liferay` bundled with `tomcat` . Application Portal is accessed using `Apache httpd` as front-end.

The issue started for us when we migrated from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` . For `HTTPS` , initially we generated self signed certificate for `Apache httpd` .  But we can see only Home Page is loaded with `HTTPS` , rest of the pages/links are using `HTTP` only. On investigating , we noted that under `Site Pages settings` in `control panel` for `Liferay` , 'Friendly URL`has`http`hard-coded in the URL .  We need to`Liferay`to use`HTTPS`instead of`HTTP`

How to configure the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because all links generated with Liferay use http protocol by default. To change this it's enough to set following property in your portal-ext.properties:

```
#
# Set the preferred protocol.
#
web.server.protocol=https
```

Article: https://www.permeance.com.au/web/tim.telcik/home/-/blogs/how-do-i-configure-apache-httpd-and-liferay-portal-to-use-ssl